# django M2M save (after POST)

Tags: python, django, formset, inline-formset, m2m

I have a form in a formset that allows a user to select email lists that they want to be included in (via checkboxes). The list is populated from a query:

`form.fields['email_list'].queryset = EmailList.objects.filter(is_active=True, is_visible=True)`

There are also email lists that are not visible to the user (`is_visible=False`).  The user can't see these records but if the admin has added the user to one of these lists (through the Admin panel), those lists need to be saved with any changes that the user makes to the list that he can see.

It seems to me that I need to take the object from the POST and append the output of a query (... `is_visible=False`) to it. Then I can save it and all of those M2M records will be saved. However I can't get it to work.

The View for the formset looks like this:

```
        FamilyInlineFormSet = modelformset_factory(Family, extra=0, formset=FamilyBaseFormSet)
FamilyMemberInlineFormSet = modelformset_factory(FamilyMember,
    extra=0, formset=FamilyMemberBaseFormSet)

if request.method == "POST":
    family_formset = FamilyInlineFormSet(request.POST,  request.FILES,
            queryset=Family.objects.filter(id=request.user.family.id), prefix='f')
    family_member_formset = FamilyMemberInlineFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES,
            queryset=FamilyMember.objects.filter(family=request.user.family.id), prefix='fm')
    if family_formset.is_valid() and family_member_formset.is_valid():

        ####### HERE IS WHERE THE CODE SHOULD GO, I BELIEVE #############

        family_formset.save()
        family_member_formset.save()
        return redirect('/school/thanks/')
else:
    family_formset = FamilyInlineFormSet(queryset=Family.objects.filter(id=request.user.family.id), prefix='f')
    family_member_formset = FamilyMemberInlineFormSet(queryset=FamilyMember.objects.filter(family=request.user.family.id), prefix='fm')

context = RequestContext(request,{
    'family_formset': family_formset,
    'family_member_formset': family_member_formset,
})
return render_to_response("school/family/manage_family_members.html", context)
```

Here is the entry in the model file:

```
    email_list = models.ManyToManyField('EmailList', verbose_name="Email Lists", blank=True, null=True)
```

Can someone point me to how I might accomplish this?

Comment: it's a complex and specific question. Please upload the project to github and share so I can have a look at some context.

Comment: https://github.com/acer123acer123/fred    Be kind... I am a UNIX/SAN admin by trade and so my programming skills are sub-par. :)

Comment: I'll try to take a look at it tomorrow, otherwise on monday.